# Using fftw fft correctly

Tags: python, c, numpy, fftw

I want to use the fft-function from the fftw-library in my project, and therefore created the following functions:

```
void fft(const int size, DCOMPLEX *a, DCOMPLEX *b)
{
    fftw_plan p;
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(size, a, b, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p); /* repeat as needed */
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
}
```

and

```
static fftw_complex *in;
static fftw_complex *out;
static fftw_plan p_fft, p_ifft;
void init_fft(const int N)
{
    in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
    if(fftw_init_threads() != 0)
    {
        printf("Using %d threads!\n", omp_get_max_threads());
        fftw_plan_with_nthreads(omp_get_max_threads());
    };
    p_fft = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE);
    p_ifft = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE);
    memset(in, 0, N);
    memset(out, 0, N);

}
void fft_pre_plan(const int size, DCOMPLEX *a, DCOMPLEX *b)
{
    memcpy(in, a, size*sizeof(DCOMPLEX));
    fftw_execute(p_ifft); /* repeat as needed */
    memcpy(b, out, size*sizeof(DCOMPLEX));
}
```

I compare the result with the results from `b = numpy.fft.fft(a)` while calling them either like

```
fft(a.size(), a, b)
```

or

```
init_fft(a.size())//Called once
fftw_pre_plan(a.size(), a, b)//Called for each fft
```

with `.size()` the length of the array (pseudo code). 
While the latter approach is a speedup of 2 compared to the numpy code, the results I obtain from it are not correct (i.e. wrong values). Why?
Edit: And if you suggest me to use the python wrappers: They do not offer me the same speedup as I get when using the latter solution (even slower than numpy).
When comparing them, I get the following values as output (for an array of `2**14` elements and the same inputs):

```
numpy.fft.fft: [ 0.00095184 -1.54074866e-32j  0.00095267 +6.52776772e-18j
  0.00095349 +2.58018535e-18j ...,  0.00095432 +1.26416719e-16j
  0.00095349 +2.61724648e-16j  0.00095267 +1.21645986e-16j]

fft(): [ 0.00095184 -1.54074866e-32j  0.00095267 -5.98482633e-17j
  0.00095349 -1.27638146e-16j ...,  0.00095432 -9.88543196e-16j
  0.00095349 -9.30058376e-16j  0.00095267 -1.09881551e-15j]

fft_pre_plan(): [ 0.00095184 -1.54074866e-32j  0.00095267 -1.09881551e-15j
  0.00095349 -9.30058376e-16j ...,  0.00095432 -1.79405492e-16j
  0.00095349 -1.27638146e-16j  0.00095267 -5.98482633e-17j]
```

Could the reason be that I have rounding errors?

Comment: What value are you passing as `size` in your calls to `memcpy` - it should be no of *bytes* but it looks like you might be passing no of *elements*?

Comment: Thanks, that is my first mistake! But it does not calculate the correct values...

Comment: Your `memset` calls have a similar problem too, but that is also probably not particularly relevant in this instance.

Comment: differences on the order of 10^(-15) or less can be expected as floating point rounding errors.

Comment: @PaulR: F*, I should not switch between python and C all the time, thanks!

Comment: @SleuthEye: Do you know how I can decrease them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `double` precision arithmetic, rounding errors on the order of 10<sup>-16</sup> to 10<sup>-15</sup> can be expected from many FFT implementations as shown in [FFTW accuracy benchmarks](http://www.fftw.org/accuracy/index.html).

Note that 10<sup>-15</sup> is 300dB less than a peak magnitude of 1.0. Most practical signals have a much smaller dynamic range (eg. [16-bit CD quality audio has an SNR of ~90dB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range#cite_note-Fries2005-12)). If your application does really need that much precision, you would likely need to use an arbitrary precision implementation of the FFT (that's what is used as a reference implementation in [FFTW accuracy measurements](http://www.fftw.org/accuracy/method.html)).